# How XSLT handles regex \w?

Tags: regex, xslt

I have an intput xml file with the name of "718322_c341b0-TEST_NOC_20160423121052.XML", which in my XSLT is assigned to $SourceFile. I am trying to test if the $SourceFile contains the string of "-TEST" using the following code:

```
<xsl:if test="matches($SourceFile, '^\w+-TEST.*')">
```

However, it did not match. So I updated the code to

```
<xsl:if test="matches($SourceFile, '^[A-Za-z0-9_]+-TEST.*')">
```

Then I got a match. I did more testing and the following code got a match, too.

```
<xsl:if test="matches($SourceFile, '^\w+_\w+-TEST.*')">
```

Here's what confused me, I think \w means [A-Za-z0-9_], correct? Why \w did not work in this case? It seems to have a trouble including the underscore. Thanks!

Comment: Check your testing scenario, you have an issue somewhere in the code that you do not show.

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? See https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#charcter-classes, the class `\w` is defined as `[#x0000-#x10FFFF]-[\p{P}\p{Z}\p{C}]`, explained as 'all characters except the set of "punctuation", "separator" and "other" characters', that seems to exclude `_`.

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#charcter-classes, the class `\w` is defined as `[#x0000-#x10FFFF]-[\p{P}\p{Z}\p{C}]`, explained as 'all characters except the set of "punctuation", "separator" and "other" characters', that seems to exclude `_`.